# Why changing switch in TableViewCell affects other switches in other cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I am struggling with my `UISwitch` in a custom `TableViewCell`.

The switch in the `UITableViewCell` adds the item from the cell to another array. However, I have noticed that when I change a switch it also changes other switches in other cells.

I believe the issue is with the TableView `dequeueReusableCell` function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "currencyCell") as? currencyCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
}
```

Comment: That's not enough code to tell what the problem is, but I assume you're not resetting the value of the `UISwitch` in your `tableView:cellForRowAt:` method before returning the cell?

Comment: Please briefly explain whats your question?

Comment: Hello TawaNicolas, you are right, I could not manage to reset it. Can you tell me how to do it? I am able access it via "cell.switchBtn(UISwitch)". However, don't know what to put in (UISwitch) part. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the switch's value somewhere "outside" the `UITableviewCell` to be able to reset it to the last value that the specific switch was in that cell. 
I recommend to save it from the cell (e.g. when `UISwitch's` value changed) with a delegate pattern. Then set it from the `tableView:cellForRowAt:` function after you dequed the cell.

Comment: Hello Bence, 
I was actually already handled setting the UISwitch with the delegate method in the prototype cell. However I could not find a way to set it at tableView:cellForRowAt: function before return cell. Only option I am getting is "cell.switchBtn(UISwitch)". So how can I set this to isOn == false so the new cells will not be effected. Thank you so much!

Comment: About that, read this article pls: https://makeapppie.com/2016/10/17/custom-table-view-cells-in-swift-3/

Comment: Hello Bence, I have read the article, however it did not mention changing value of Prototype Cell's childs. I just want to know how I can change value of UISwitch inside TableView:cellForRowAt prior to returning new cells. Thank you for your time and answers. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to create a UITableViewCell subclass e.g. SwitchTableViewCell, then in the cellForRowAt method you cast the dequeued cell like: if let switchCell = cell as? SwitchTableViewCell. And if you connect the switch from storyboard cell to this SwitchTableViewCell with an outlet, you will be able to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. Asked a senior developer, and he suggested that because in the `UITableView` cells are reused. When one changes the state of the first `UISwitch` in the `UITableView` to ON and scrolls down, the cell with the first switch is reused, hence some of the subsequent switches are displayed as ON by default.

Turning the first `UISwitch` ON is not changing the state of other switches in the `UITableView`. Instead, the first switch is being reused.

So, the solution to this would be to bind the `UISwitch` in every cell with some data. As an example (pseudocode):

```
public class ABC: UITableViewCell
{
    .
    .
    .
    .
    public void UpdateCell(bool switchStatus)
    {
        SwitchInCell.On = switchStatus
    }
}
```

**UpdateCell** method is called from a class that inherits `UITableViewSource` class.

(**Note:**  I am from C# background and developing for iOS using Xamarin. So above pseudocode is in C#. But can be very easily transferred to Swift.)

I hope this helped.